# Making a c++ function cross platform with "runtime importing"

Tags: c++, import

I was writing this simple function that updates the terminal size:

```
bool DisplayManager::getWindowSize(){
    Vector windowsize; // Class with h and w attributes and operator overloading
    #ifdef __linux__ 
    try{
        #include<sys/ioctl.h>
        #include<unistd.h> 
        struct winsize window;
        ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &window);
        windowsize.w = window.ws_col;
        windowsize.h = window.ws_row;
    }catch(...){
        return false;
    }
    #elif _WIN32 | _WIN64
    try{
        #include<windows.h>
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
        newWindowsize.w = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.rsWindow.Left + 1;
        newWindowsize.h = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.rsWindow.Top + 1;
    }catch(...){
        return false;
    }
    #endif
    mWindowsize = windowsize;
    return true;
}
```

I tried to make it cross-platform and added an *if else* with one branch importing two linux specific libraries and the other impoting a windows library but this doesn't work.

I tried to come up with a solution that would work but I couldn't really think about anything.

If it's possible I'd like to keep the function in one block and not have two separate file, one per os.

Comment: Why? What's the benefit of smooshing two completely independent implementations into a single function body? This function is part of an abstraction layer, and it's completely normal to have separate platform-specific implementations of the same interface. Also: what on earth do you expect to `catch` from an `ioctl` call?

Comment: dont `#include` things in the middle of a function like that. that header is literally being copy pasted in the middle of the function. I wouldnt expect anything good from that.

Comment: @Useless Maybe `Vector::w` has a throwing assignment operator :)

Comment: @user2079303 not really, I added it just in case there would be some runtime problem but I guess it's useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `#include` library headers into a function, and expect it to work (unless it's a very unconventional library whose documentation says that you need to do that). You must include them in the global scope:

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<unistd.h> 
#elif _WIN32 | _WIN64
#include<windows.h>
#endif

bool DisplayManager::getWindowSize(){
```

> Making a c++ function cross platform with “runtime importing”

You cannot "import" headers at runtime. That said, `__linux__`, `_WIN32` and `_WIN64` are defined at pre-processing time, so there's no need here to "import" headers at runtime.

Comment: "You can't #include library headers into a function" - Well, you *can*. It's just usually a bad idea ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl (-: I amended just in case someone doesn't get what I meant.